# How to link entire article content as menu

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, articles, menu

How to link entire article content (including text, paragraph, etc.) as menu in Joomla. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Entire above block I want as menu

Thanks

Comment: See the official docs [Adding a menu item which points to an Article](http://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Menus_Menu_Item_Article_Single_Article) Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, This is not working for me.

Comment: @webanup - What do you mean not working? Assuming you simply want to have a menu item that links to your article, all you need to do for the menu item is set the **type** to **Single Article** and then select the article you want to link it to. If you need something else, then please explain in more detail in your question

Comment: I don't want to link any article to menu item. I want entire article content (including text, paragraph, images etc.) as hyperlink. So that I can add hyperlinked article to menu item and menu module. Thanks

Comment: Can any one please specify, it is possible or not in Joomla. I am running out of time. I have to complete this task as soon as possible. - Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4512/module-as-menu-item/4540#4540) might help solve your problem? It's a bit technical, but it's a method to add a module in your main menu, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very vague, and parts of it doesn't make sense (`add hyperlinked article to menu item and menu module`, for instance). You're mixing the terms [module](/questions/tagged/module), [articles](/questions/tagged/articles), [url](/questions/tagged/url)[menu](/questions/tagged/menu) and others.

But as far as I understand, you have one (or more) blocks like the image in your question, and you want to link them to an article with details about the hotel. What you need is the link to the article in question. This can be achieved in several ways. Choose the option that fits your needs:

### Get link in editor

In your article editor (I assume you're using TinyMCE), you can create a link to any existing article with the "Article" button below the text window:

[image: Article Link]

This will insert a direct link to the article, with the article title as the link text. To see the actual link, click the "Source Code" button in the toolbar and copy the link parameter.

[image: Source code view]

Then simply paste the link you copied into an `<a>` tag surrounding your block.

### Hidden menu

You can also create a new menu (**Menus** -> **Menu Manager** -> **Add New Menu**) and call it whatever you like ("Hidden" is a good idea). The menu will be invisible to users unless you publish it to a module position.

Then create a new menu item in this hidden menu for each article you want to link to (for instructions, see the [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Help33:Menus_Menu_Item_Article_Single_Article) provided by johnny_s). Notice the field "Alias":

[image: Alias field]

The alias field will be the link to your article. Once you save the menu item, you can link to the article like this:

```
http://YOURSITE.com/index.php/YOURALIAS
```

or

index.php/YOURALIAS

Replace `YOURALIAS` with the alias of your menu item.

*(Note that this will only work if you enabled "Search Engine Friendly URLs" in Global Configuration)*

### Create the link manually

You can create the link like this:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=XX&Itemid=YY
```

Replace `XX` with the article ID (you can find this in the article manager, in the right-most column). The last part (`&Itemid=YY`) is optional, but if you replace `YY` with the ID of an existing menu item, the page layout (published modules etc.) will match this menu item.

### Use JCE

The popular editor JCE ([Joomla Content Editor](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/88/details)) will allow you to create a link to any existing article. Instructions can be found here: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/documentation/25-links/271-interface

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I tried with hidden menu and created article and I linked article inside another article. But finally when I published in menu module, its just displaying menu title, its not displaying article content. 

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand of your question, you want to call content into your menu output.

This is absolutely possible, but it requires a bit of skill and understanding of Joomla.

Instead of making your content an article, make your content in a module. Then you call that module into your menu item using a mega menu (such as [CKMaximenu](http://www.joomlack.fr/en/joomla-extensions/maximenu-ck)) and its paid plugin.

Or utilize [NoNumber](http://nonumber.nl), a combination of rereplacer, modules anywhere, or sourcerer would do it.